# paste data based on certain condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, awk

experts i have many files in a directory and these files contain some numerical numbers.

Comment: Given all of the questions that get slammed for not having enough information I can't believe this got multiple answers. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not POSIX-compatible; tested on Bash 5.0. Assuming that the filenames don't contain whitespaces and have fixed length.

```sh
for file_with_a in *A.??
do
  target_left=${file_with_a:0:15} # e.g., 2019__01_NDV.NT
  target_right=${file_with_a:16:3} # e.g., .AS
  cat $target_left[A-C]$target_right > ${target_left}_ABC$target_right
done
```

Comment: You'll definitely want to copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 1):

With `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]__*[ABC]*.??)

while mapfile -d '' -n3 array && ((${#array[*]} == 3)); do
  if [[ ${array[0]%%_*} == ${array[1]%%_*} && ${array[0]%%_*} == ${array[2]%%_*}  ]]; then
    paste "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}" > "${array[0]%${array[0]:(-4)}}_ABC.${array[0]:(-2)}"
  fi
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}")
```